# Something like setter and getter for a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, getter-setter

I have the following problem:
A class contains a dict of dicts of dicts ... e.g.

```
class Try():
   def __init__(self):
     self._tryDict = {'first':{'b':{'bla':'x'},'c':1},'second':{'b':15,'c':1}}
 @getter 
 def tryDict....

 @tryDict.setter 
 def tryDict....
```

I would like to have now something like setter and getter to change a variable at a certain level of the dict and retrun the **corresponding** dict a view levels above (and only if i set a new value)
e.g.

```
try = Try()
try.tryDict['first']['b']['bla']
```

returs: `'x'`

```
try.tryDict['first']['b']['bla']='z'
```

changes `'x'` to `'z'` and returns the content of try.tryDict['first'] (`{'b':{'bla':'x'},'c':1}`)

To understand why I need this:
The dict is actually a list of file-praser-functions and the content is also stored as a dict.
i.e.

```
dict = {'file-1':dict-1, 'file-1':dict-1, 'file-1':dict-1, ...}
```

with `dict['file-1']['content-3']=1`  I set the new content
and with  `dict['file-1'].write()`, the content of the file is updated in the file. The dict is a class instance and I would like to immediately wirte the change to the file.

many thx for your help!
BR, maths

Comment: The methods to override are `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`. However, it gets tricky, because the mapping protocol doesn't specify that an object needs to know what other object contains it. Your custom mapping class will need to implement that itself.

Comment: This seems like a ton of complication to (correct me if I'm wrong) turn two lines of code into one line of code.  I think a more pythonic solution would be to wrap these operations into a function; `update_dict_and_write_file` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so what I implemented it now this way:

Each file got setter and getter function

```
class dicts():
.....
# to show the content
 @getter 
 def tryDict(self):
     return tryDict.file
# to sett some content
 @tryDict.setter 
 def tryDict(self, entry):
     if len(entry)==2:
        name, newEntry =  entry
        tryDict.file[name]= newEntry
     if len(entry)==3:
   ....
```

if i whan to get the entry:

```
tryDicis = dicts()
tryDicis.trydict # shows the dictionary
```

i can now set in different levels like:

```
tryDicis = dicts()
tryDicis.trydict = (name-level-1, name-level-2,..., newEntry)
```

This is maybe not the most elegant way, however it is easy to implement and good enough in my case.
BR, maths